# Save data from database to <option> in HTML

Tags: php, html, database

I would like to save variable from database to `<option>`.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM classes");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();

    ?>
    <script>var select_class = document.getElementById('select_class');</script>";

    <?php
        foreach ($result as $to_result)
        {
    ?>
            <script>
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = "<?php echo($to_result['name']); ?>";
                select_class.appendChild(option);
            </script>

            <?php

        }
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<select id="select_class"></select>
```

Database:

ID_class[1] = something

...

ID_class[12] = something

**TypeError: select_class is null**
But why? I dont know what is my problem.

Comment: Does your JavaScript look for the element before it exists in the DOM? Can you generate the HTML with only PHP? It seems that JavaScript may not be necessary here.

Comment: So how can I save row to <option>?

Comment: Can you say "show" instead of "save", you are showing data and not saving it. And you don't need JS to show the data, you can output it directly to an HTML structure.

Comment: Is your javascript code above or below that `<select>` in your code? Since your code is not triggered by an event it should be below the `<select>` or it won't exist yet when you call `document.getElementById()`

Comment: @rickdenhaan It was the problem. Now I do not get any error. Count of options in select is 12. That is right, but every option is without value, so I just see 12 white options. Why?

Comment: @J.Doe That's because you're only setting `option.value`, which is not displayed. You need to set the displayed label as well using `option.text`

Comment: @rickdenhaan That is work great. Thanks. Next to the <option> `is ";`. I do not see, where in code I echo it. Do you see this a little mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several mistakes in you code. For example, you reopened a script tag while the old one wasn't even closed.

Besides that, I don't think that the javascript was needed in this code. I've simplified it for you:

```
<select id="select_class">
    <?php
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM classes");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $to_result)
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $to_result['name']; ?>">
            <?php echo $to_result['name']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```